# Mongodb filemd5 command exception

Tags: mongodb, exception, md5

I have mongodb exception. In my team this exception appears only on me PC. I can't figure out why did it happen and how to solve it. I've already drop mondodb, repair it..nothing helps. Can somebody help or give me advice how to fix?

```
CommandDocument commandDocument = new CommandDocument("filemd5", files_id);
var md5 = mongoGridFs.Database.RunCommand(commandDocument);
```

Exception look like this:

```
Command 'filemd5' failed: need an index on { files_id : 1 , n : 1 } 
(response: { "errmsg" : "need an index on { files_id : 1 , n : 1 }", "ok" : 0.0 })
```